# Multiple Bokeh Server Integration To Flask

Tags: python, flask, tornado, bokeh

I am trying to run multiple Bokeh servers in the flask app , the plots function correctly on their own using method like this:

```
  def getTimePlot():
   script = server_document('http://localhost:5006/timeseries')
   return render_template("displaytimeseries.html", script=script, template="Flask")    
def startPlotserver():
    server.start()
    server = Server({'/timeseries': modifyTimeSeries}, io_loop=IOLoop(), allow_websocket_origin=["localhost:8000"])
    server.io_loop.start() 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Opening single process Flask app with embedded Bokeh application on http://localhost:8000/')
    print()
    print('Multiple connections may block the Bokeh app in this configuration!')
    print('See "flask_gunicorn_embed.py" for one way to run multi-process')
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

but when i try to embed two servers together to flask using this approach that's where i get the problems:

**file structure:**

```
|--app4
    |---webapp2.py
    |---bokeh
          |--timeseries.py
          |--map.py
```

I think i have found the workaround in here [Link To Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256853/modulating-bokeh-servers-within-flask/55265087#55265087) 
I am have trying now to import the map server to flak using the similar method mentioned and ended up with something like this:

**1. File builder (not sure why it's not picking it up)**

```
def build_single_handler_applications(paths, argvs=None):
applications = {}
argvs = {} or argvs
for path in paths:
    application = build_single_handler_application(path, argvs.get(path, []))
    route = application.handlers[0].url_path()
    if not route:
        if '/' in applications:
            raise RuntimeError("Don't know the URL path to use for %s" % (path))
    route = '/'
    applications[route] = application
return applications
```

**2. Code to find file and create connection**

```
    files=[]
for file in os.listdir("bokeh"):
    if file.endswith('.py'):
        file="map"+file
        files.append(file)

argvs = {}
urls = []
for i in files:
    argvs[i] = None
    urls.append(i.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0])
host = 'http://localhost:5006/map'

apps = build_single_handler_applications(files, argvs)

bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado(apps, extra_websocket_origins=["localhost:8000"])
bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado)
sockets, port = bind_sockets("localhost:8000", 5000)
bokeh_http.add_sockets(sockets)
```

**3. Code which calls the server and renders template**

```
    @app.route('/crimeMap', methods=['GET'])
def getCrimeMap():
    bokeh_script = server_document("http://localhost:5006:%d/map" % port) 
    return render_template("displaymap1.html", bokeh_script=bokeh_script)
```

i am running both of my Bokeh servers in single command like this

```
bokeh serve timeseries.py map.py --allow-websocket-origin=127.0.0.1:5000
```

but when i run webapp2.py i am getting this error:

```
    (env1) C:\Users\Dell1525\Desktop\flaskapp\env1\app4>webapp2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell1525\Desktop\flaskapp\env1\app4\webapp2.py", line 113, in <module>
    apps = build_single_handler_applications(files, argvs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell1525\Desktop\flaskapp\env1\app4\webapp2.py", line 29, in build_single_handler_applications
    application = build_single_handler_application(path, argvs.get(path, []))
NameError: name 'build_single_handler_application' is not defined
```

i found and added build_single_handler_application function from Bokeh docs only because of this error so i am not sure if it was even required or is correct. I am wondering what am i missing to make this work just in case it is positioning error or missing imports i am attaching full flask webapp2.py code here :

[Full Code](https://pastebin.com/fyN4ZPCN)

Thak you so much for help

Answer (score 0):

i have found an easier solution by tweaking this example a little: [Link To Original Post](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/m/?fbclid=IwAR1AuxJZnYjQutm4T8RHc0sx-pVg8rSFlWp1C9DosSCImvj0pdKgpjwSxVg#!msg/bokeh/LYmjTXzX43E/_0dNPR1_CQAJ) Note this requires you to have tornado 4.4.1 as its not working with newer versions

trick is to run all servers individually and on different ports with same socket access like this

```
  bokeh serve timeseries.py --port 5100 --allow-websocket-origin=localhost:5567

bokeh serve map.py --port 5200 --allow-websocket-origin=localhost:5567
```

for those who might find this useful i have included full working solution [Link To Working Code](https://pastebin.com/8Uz11bfV)

Comment: The "Link To Working Code" is broke. Can you share the code here?